# SQL Unique Indexes

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables (simplified) - Trucks and Trailers

**Trucks**

```
TruckID  int identity
Trailer1 int null
Trailer2 int null
```

**Trailers**

```
TrailerID int identity
```

Since the trailer foreign keys are nullable, a truck can either have no trailers at all, have one trailer or have two trailers.

How can I build an Index on the Trucks table to ensure that the same TrailerID can never be used twice?

For one trailer, I can create a computed field

```
IsNull(TrailerID, -1 * TruckID)
```

and create a unique index on this. But how do I manage this for two trailers?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create an indexed view which would effectively union the trailers.

For this, you would have to create a tiny supporting table:

```
CREATE TABLE place (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT
INTO    place
VALUES  (1),
        (2)

GO

CREATE VIEW
        v_truck_trailers
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
        SELECT  t.id AS truckId,
                p.id AS placeId,
                CASE p.id WHEN 1 THEN trailer1 WHEN 2 THEN trailer2 END AS trailerId
        FROM    dbo.truck t
        JOIN    dbo.place p
        ON      CASE p.id WHEN 1 THEN trailer1 WHEN 2 THEN trailer2 END IS NOT NULL
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
        ux_v_truck_trailers_truck_place
ON      v_truck_trailers (truckId, placeId)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
        ux_v_truck_trailers_trailer
ON      v_truck_trailers (trailerId)
GO
```

Now let's try it:

```
INSERT
INTO    truck
VALUES  (1, 1, NULL) -- succeeds

INSERT
INTO    truck
VALUES  (2, 2, 3) -- also succeeds

INSERT
INTO    truck
VALUES  (3, NULL, 2) -- fails as trailer 2 is already used on truck 2, even if on another place.
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb1344/1).

Comment: Seems like a lot of unnecessary complexity for a simple task. Is there any simpler way?

Comment: @arjun: how do you think, if there were a more simple way, would I suggest a complex one?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do this with indexes alone. You need to have your identities as you have. I think you will have to impliment a trigger on your update to roll it back if a violation occurs which will ensure that the trailerID does not exist in either

```
Select Trailer1 FROM Trucks
UNION
Select Trailer2 FROM Trucks
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189799%28v=sql.105%29.aspx for triggers

You should still have indexes on  both Trailer1 and Trailer2 so that the optimiser can just look up if the TrailerID exists in either column.

Comment: Agree. It might even be easier to write an SP to first run a Select statement to check for the existence of a Trailer before attempting to update or insert. But I was looking for a elegant solution using indexes.

Comment: Well, I dont like triggers because they can be very hard to debug. You could create a view on the union, then (you should be able to) make the resultant column unique. (I suspect there would be a trigger going on under the hood.) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28v=sql.80%29.aspx suggests this should work

Comment: @IanP: you can't create an indexed view on a `UNION`.

Comment: Quite right, Q thanks, when I was checking the docs, I misread... You even get a helpful error when you try. Well I guess the SP route is the best and probably the most maintainable....

Answer (score 1):

If you can change table structure, I would recommend third table TrailersTrucks

```
TrailersTrucks

TrailersTrucksID int identity
TruckID  int not null
TrailerID int not null
[TrailerNo int] - optional
```

Change Trucks declaration

```
Trucks

TruckID  int identity
TrailersTrucksID int null
```

Then you can use unique index on TrailerID. You might also want to introduce TrailerNo and constrain it to 1 and 2 values (or use enum) plus add unique index on TruckID and TrailerNo... this way it will be impossible to add 3 and more trailers to the truck... you can always extend constraint if you need it (f.ex. for trains).

This is suggested way to solve the problem, you'll get normalized database then.

However I know it is not always possible for many reasons :)

Comment: Yes. This would have been the obvious way out for a new project. Unfortunately, it is not an option for us to create a many-to-many relationship at this time. It would complicate a lot of SQL in other parts of the app. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can have UNIQUE constraint on Traileid1 and TrailerId2 seperately.

```
CREATE TABLE Trailers
(
TrailerID int identity PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
t_type varchar(10) null
)


CREATE TABLE Trucks
(
TruckID  int identity PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Trailer1 int UNIQUE null,
Trailer2 int UNIQUE null
FOREIGN KEY ( Trailer1 ) REFERENCES Trailers(TrailerID),
FOREIGN KEY ( Trailer2 ) REFERENCES Trailers(TrailerID),
)
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to prevent a value that appeared in `Trailer1` once from appearing in `Trailer2` at all (and vice versa)